# Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [] PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder

Tags: java, ssl, bazel, keytool

I am getting this error.

```
(08:45:12) WARNING: Download from https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/0.8.0.tar.gz failed: class javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
(08:45:12) ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'rules_foreign_cc':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/apollo_project/apollo/.cache/bazel/b52035c489e6fe2bd45e6bc6d0d71be2/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 132, column 45, in _http_archive_impl
        download_info = ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://apollo-system.bj.bcebos.com/archive/6.0/rules_foreign_cc-0.8.0.tar.gz, 
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/0.8.0.tar.gz] to /home/apollo_project/apollo/.cache/bazel/b52035c489e6fe2bd45e6bc6d0d71be2/external/rules_foreign_cc/
temp5947386906325017422/rules_foreign_cc-0.8.0.tar.gz: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This occurred when building to use open source called apollo. 
It seems that the part that downloads the file using Bazel is in the build script, but that error occurred.
I also set as below.

```
keytool -importcert -alias startsl -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file my.crt
```

The basic proxy setting of the docker container has been set. 
The part where download is attempted in the build script I also confirmed that download is successful with wget.
(wget https://apollo-system.bj.bcebos.com/archive/6.0/rules_foreign_cc-0.8.0.tar.gz, 
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/0.8.0.tar.gz)
What more settings do I need?

Comment: Likely this is your answer : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162592/why-do-i-need-to-add-intermediate-ca-certificates-to-jvms-cacerts-file#162595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following settings.
I create [~/.bazelrc] and add the following contents

```
startup --host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8u342-b07/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
        --host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

And I add the following contents to [~/.bashrc] as well.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8u342-b07
```

And it was solved after restarting my docker container.
Of course, I have already set the settings below.

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file my.crt
```